# FFMPEG Audio streaming over RTP

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, rtp

I have a encoded Audio File(.aac file). I want to stream this file over RTP using FFMPEG without any transcoding. I am using following command :

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.aac -re -vn -acodec copy -strict experimental -f rtp rtp://225.0.0.1:1234
```

But above command gives below error:

```
AAC with no global headers is currently not supported
```

Can anyone point out any corrections ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The warning means it wants global headers to be set on your audio stream, like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input_file.aac -c:a copy -flags:a +global_headers -f rtp rtp://225.0.0.1:1234
```

Comment: Added Global headers flag. still same issue.